# aiogram FMS сброс состояния

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio

через FSM машину состояний запрашиваю у пользователя время
в конце, если пользователь не прислал время - сбрасываю состояние

```
time_task = await callback_query.message.edit_text(
    text=f"Введите время в минутах по задаче\n<b>{name}</b>", parse_mode='html')
await state.set_state(states.TimesheetEmployees.time_task)
await asyncio.sleep(30)
if await state.get_state() == 'TimesheetEmployees:time_task':
    await callback_query.message.edit_text(text='Время ожидания превышено')
    await callback_query.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=kb)
    await state.finish()
```

то есть через 30 секунд, если пользователь на том же состоянии, то состояние сбрасывается, чтобы вечно не ждать ответа от пользователя
В чем собственно проблема.
Например пользователь зашел, ввел время, состояние закрылось через state.finish().
Потом пользователь снова заходит списать время
и вот тут await asyncio.sleep(30) - считает не 30 секунд, а время от первого ввода времени
например пользователь зашел ввел время в 13:31:00 - первый раз,
состояние закрылось,
зашел снова сразу, решил ещё раз ввести данные например в 13:31:20
и в 13:31:30 состояние сбрасывается, хотя по идее должно сбрасываться через 30 секунд в 13:31:50.
Куда поставить asyncio.sleep() чтобы оно считало время правильно

Answer (score 0):

Каждый раз когда бот запрашивает время у пользователя, у тебя запускается таймер на 30 секунд. И он сработает в любом случае.

В течение этих 30 секунд, можно несколько раз запросить время. И все равно самый первый таймер сработает и очистит состояние. Потому что первый таймер не знает о других таймерах.

Поэтому нужно сделать так, чтобы знал. Можно использовать `data` в `state`.
Например каждый раз когда запускается таймер, ты генерируешь уникальное число, которое будет ассоциироваться только с этим таймером и сохранишь его в `state`. Если запущен другой таймер, то он поставит туда свое случайное число.

Только таймер, который последним установил свое число, может очистить состояние. Для этого будет достаточно проверить что сохраненное число в `state`.

```
time_task = await callback_query.message.edit_text(
    text=f"Введите время в минутах по задаче\n<b>{name}</b>", parse_mode='html')
await state.set_state(states.TimesheetEmployees.time_task)

time_task_timer_id = random.randint(1, 99999)
await state.update_data(time_task_timer_id=time_task_timer_id)

await asyncio.sleep(30)

data = await state.get_data()
actual_time_task_timer_id = data.get("time_task_timer_id")
if await state.get_state() == 'TimesheetEmployees:time_task' and actual_time_task_timer_id == time_task_timer_id:
    await callback_query.message.edit_text(text='Время ожидания превышено')
    await callback_query.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=kb)
    await state.finish()
```

Это один из способов. Главное чтобы несколько таймеров как-то могли обмениваться информацией. Это можно сделать через `data` в `state`.

Также можно сохранять дату запуска таймера и через 30 секунд проверять, действительно ли прошло 30 секунд.

Comment: это сработало, только важный момент, уникальное число надо генерировать и записывать в словарь перед вызовом состояния, иначе так же сбрасывает через первые 30 сек